# Ring of integers of the maximal totally real subfield of CM field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

Let $K$ be a CM field and $F$ the maximal totally real subfield of $K$. We assume the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the form $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha, \beta]$. Then can we determine the form of $\mathcal{O}_F$?
For example, assume $K= \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ be a cyclotomic field, then $\mathcal{O}_K = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta]$ and $\mathcal{O}_F = \mathbb{Z}[\zeta + \zeta^{-1}]$. From this example, I expect that $\mathcal{O}_F = \mathbb{Z}[\alpha + \beta, \alpha\beta]$, but I don't know the proof.

Also, can this fact be generalized a little more?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you assuming that $\beta=\overline\alpha$?

Comment: Yes. But doesn't it hold for $/beta /neq /overline{/alpha}$?

Comment: When $\beta\ne\overline\alpha$ then one can't expect $\alpha+\beta$ and $\alpha\beta$ to lie in $F$.

Comment: I guess so, well, do you have any idea of the proof?

Comment: With $K = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ CM then $F = \mathbb{Q}(\alpha+\overline{\alpha},\alpha\overline{\alpha})$.